# Symfony 2.8 -> 3.4 local development speed decrease

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, page-load-time

after upgrading from 2.8 to 3.4.14 we are experiencing way longer pageloads on local development machines (OSX).

### load times

simple /login page (cache pre-warmed):

- nginx+php-fpm app.php:  **6 seconds**
- nginx+php-fpm app_dev.php:  **10-12 seconds**
- console server:run dev: **10-12 seconds**

### PHP config

xdebug completely not enabled in php.ini, further config to speed up things:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=240
```

### profiler data

[image]

[image]

Counting the milliseconds here doesn't get us to the 10 seconds it took to initialize Symfony... right?

Any suggestions on where else to look for the bottleneck?

Thanks a lot,

Kim

Comment: PHP version? Other than that, check out Symfony profiling or generic PHP profiling. One quick fix might be `composer install -o`, though that doesn't explain the performance decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was a weird one. It seems to have been my hosts file and local dns resolution. Once I changed `/private/etc/hosts` from this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
127.0.0.1 myotherproject.dev
```

to this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myproject.dev myotherproject.dev
```

no delay, from 11 seconds down to 200ms :)

Got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon).