# Why are my virtual hosts so slow responding?

Tags: apache, xampp

I have set up Xampp for php development on my mac studio. On monterey.

Problem is that my virtual hosts responds really slow. Sometimes up to 10 seconds to load a site. And sometimes i just get the below message in chrome, then the page reloads and try to get the page again.

```
This page isn’t workingfhm.test didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

Here's my setup:

httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName fhm.test
DocumentRoot "/applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fhm.test"
<Directory "/applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fhm.test">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is my etc/hosts.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   fhm.test
```

In the site folder it points to i only have a php info script right no. Any ideas on what the problem is and how to resolve?

Comment: Problem solved by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200111/20047355. Can't believe it worked..

Comment: In that case, this can be closed as duplicate of [How can I eliminate slow resolving/loading of localhost/virtualhost (a 2-3 second lag) on Mac OS X Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064581/how-can-i-eliminate-slow-resolving-loading-of-localhost-virtualhost-a-2-3-secon)

Answer (score 0):

My virtual host conducted -

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8080>
    ServerName MySite.com
    ServerAlias *.MySite.com
    ServerAdmin test@test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MySite.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```